# Inserting an annotation onto all plotted points?

Tags: qgis, labeling, table, annotation

I have an attribute table of 73 polling stations, and using the labelling function, I have labelled all of the points in preparation for printing on polling cards for our some 60000 electorate.

After playing with the annotation tool, I've found that it is much clearer than any variation of label I can produce - I can also then go through each annotation and re-position it so that it doesn't cover up any nearby street or building names - (as far as I can tell labels cannot be repositioned on an individual basis).

Is there any way to place an annotation onto all of the plotted points whilst retaining the same settings in respect of text font/size and the size of the annotation itself?

**Here is an image of the finalised map:**
[image: ![Here is an image of the finalised map]

**This is an image of the labels, as you can see it does not look as professional as above**:
[image: ![This is an image of the labels, as you can see it does not look as professional as above]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just programming a AHK script and going through one-by-one, only took 30 minutes or so

Answer (score 0):

You can reposition your labels by adding 2 fields, one for the x-coordinate and one for the y-coordinate.  Than you can eddit the styling properties for the labels (under placement) and assign both features.  Now you can move your labels.

More detailed info: [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183049/move-label-in-qgis)

Better would be to upgrade to QGIS3.  There this goes much easier.

Comment: Thanks - I've used this method to create the labels initially, but the annotations look much clearer in comparison, which is what I want to essentially convert the markers into