# How can I stop QGIS from drawing a line when moving a label?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have labels of a shapefile which I created through Easy Custom Labeling (labeling toolbar). I want to move the labels around manually to arrange them better but QGIS draws a line wherever I move them to. How can I disable this?

[image]

'Use custom dash pattern' was off anyway. I tried changing the line width to 0, even the pen to 'no pen' and also changed the value in the 'LblShowCO' column back to Null values. Still I have this annoying line :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EasyLabeling there is a column called `LblShowCO` which is set to 1 or 0 depending on if you have moved a label or not.
This is used to control the custom dash string in the style:

```
CASE WHEN LblShowCO = 1 
THEN 
    '2;0' 
ELSE 
    '0;2' 
END
```

The easiest way to turn off all leader lines is to turn off `Use Custom Dash Pattern` in the style. Or set the line to have 0 width, or you can
 either set all the values to that column to NULL or remove 0 and then remove the ELSE clause if you need to keep some of the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried everything but still the line is there (see screenshot above)

Comment: Okay now I tried the 'no pen' option but without setting the width to 0 which worked! Weird but it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternative solution with the QGIS build-in solution to move labels by adding 2 real-type fields to your layer (LABEL_X and LABEL_Y for example). Then you define in its properties the two field to control X and Y coordinates of your label.

[image]

Then you use the label toolbar to move your labels... with no lines :

[image]

some more infos here : [How does manual Label Placement in QGIS 1.9 work?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67408/how-does-manual-label-placement-in-qgis-1-9-work) (it works with QGIS 2.16)