# How do I label my map with attributes?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2

I have a state map in QGIS 2.0 with all of the county names and some other information listed in the attributes table.  I would like to have the name of the counties and one of the attributes visually displayed on the map in each respective county.  This should be relatively simple... but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (the simple way):

Right click layer in "Layers" box (table of contents), go to properties, go to labels, check the box "Label this layer with..." and choose the field you want to label it by from the drop down menu.  You can also play with text formatting here.

So: Right click layer > Properties > Labels > Label this layer with [field]

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  There sure is a lot of formatting you can do.  I ended up trying to move the labels using the "move label" tool, which I ended up having to follow these instructions:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/is-there-a-way-to-manually-place-labels-in-qgis

Even that isn't too simple.  I got to the point where I could move the labels, but only some were showing up and it was difficult to put them on multiple lines.

I'll probably end up using Photoshop after exporting the image to do exactly what I want.

Thanks!